# Reference request for a lemma about qc sheaves on a separated scheme

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I've proven the following easy Lemma. I wonder, where does this appear in the literature? Is there an EGA reference? I ask this because I need this Lemma in a paper and would prefer not to "waste time" with it.

> Let $X$ be a separated scheme and denote by $j : U \to X$ the inclusion of an open affine subset. Then
>
> 1. For every $M \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(X)$ the canonical homomorphism $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M \to j_* j^* M$ is an epimorphism.
> 2. For every $N \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(U)$ the direct image $j_* N$ is generated by global sections.